# cmake: how to link dll when there is d suffix for debug

Tags: cmake, vtk

I want to include a third package (VTK) in my project. The folder is:

```
Thirdparty
    VTK
        bin
            Debug
                xxxd.dll
                ...
            Release
                xxx.dll
                ...
        include
                xxx
                ...
        lib
            Debug
                xxx
                ...
            Release
                ...
```

In this package (VTK), there is `d` suffix in the dll of debug. Just like: `vtkCommonCore-9.0d.dll` (debug) vs `vtkCommonCore9.0dll` (release).

In my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(VTI_DIR "xxx/Thirdparty/VTK")
include_directories(
    ${VTK_DIR}/include
)
target_link_libraries(Pro
    vtkCommonCore-9.0
    ....
)
```

If I use `target_link_libraries(Pro vtkCommonCore-9.0d ....)`, the code would be ok for debug but wrong for release, because CMake cannot find `vtkCommonCore-9.0d.dll` in `Thirdparty/VTK/bin/Release`.

How can I implement the correct `CMakeLists.txt` for this package (VTK)?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

---

Update:

After reading the explanation of [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html), I find a solution for my problem:

```
target_link_libraries(Pro
    debug vtkCommonCore-9.0d
    optimized vtkCommonCore-9.0
)
```

However, this method seem to be inconvenient.

[target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) provides two method:

1. A plain library name

   I use it as:

   ```
   target_link_libraries(Pro -lvtkCommonCore)
   ```

   And it failed.
2. A generator expression
   I use it as:

   ```
   target_link_libraries(Pro vtkCommonCore-9.0$<1:d;2:"">)
   ```

   And it failed.

I don't know how to use the above methods.

Comment: You should use `find_file` to find libraries. You can tell CMake that the library might be named with the d suffix. Once the library is found, you just have to pass variables or even targets. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909627/2799037

Comment: Instead of doing the find_library manually you should follow the recipes described in the VTK examples (see https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/GeometricObjects/CylinderExample/)

Comment: @vre The VTK example requires that the VTK is bulit in my computer. Now, I don't want to build VTK in my computer. I want to include bin/include/lib in my computer. Thus, the find_package would be failed.

Comment: @usr1234567 Do you mean find_library? When I use `find_library(CommonCoreLIb vtkCommonCore)`, the cmake show `CommonCoreLib-NOTFOUND`. Could you please give more details?

Comment: The example should also work whithout VTK needing to be built on your computer. But it need to be installed. For using `find_package` you need to add either the VTK installation directory to your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or set the variable `VTK_DIR` to this path **before** doing the `find_package` call. Your CMakeLists.txt fragment incorrectly uses `VTI_DIR` (note the typo).

Comment: What do you want to achieve by the generator expression `$<1:d;2:"">`? For me it has no sense. If you want to construct expression "Choose 'd' for debug build and empty string otherwise", then use `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:d>`. This kind of expression is provided as an example for conditional expressions: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#conditional-expressions.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you very much. `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:d>` works. Do you know how to use the `A plain library name`? `target_link_libraries(Pro -lvtkCommonCore)` do not work.

Comment: "A plain library name" means that the library will be **searched by the linker** using this name. E.g. with `target_link_libraries(Pro vtkCommonCore)` the linker will search the library with name `vtkCommonCore`. The library will be searched only in the specific directories. E.g. for search under `VTK/bin/Release` you could use `target_link_directories(Pro ${VTK_DIR}/bin/Release)`. Note, that in CMake projects using `target_link_directories` in combination with a plain library name is **discouraged**: instead specify full path to the library file.